# how did they make the a:hover full background color

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a layout sidebar using `a:hover`. How I set the background color to be full the div? why isn't this code working?

```
<style>
#header{
background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar{
background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

#content{
background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;}

#footer{background-color: darkblue;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

a {text-decoration: none;
    color: white;}
a:active {font-size: 10px;}




li{display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;}
</style>

<div id="header">
    HEADER
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
    <a href=""> <li>Home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Annoucement</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>ReportList</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Settings</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    CONTET
</div>
<div id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
```

Is there any problem with this script, cause its show that the background color cross the sidebar div when we point the mouse to the list(hover)

[image]

Comment: share html code also

Comment: You may need to remove default `padding` and `margin` of the `<ul>`. Cannot see your HTML so this is just a guess.

Comment: HI deepu and calvin thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` has default margin. Change that `margin` to `0` and give `height`

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  height :40px;
  display :flex;
}
```

The solution:

```css
#header{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#content{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;}

#footer{
    background-color: darkblue;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

a:active {font-size: 10px;}

li{
  display: inline;    
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: dimgray;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  height :40px;
  display :flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    HEADER
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
    <a href=""> <li>Home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Annoucement</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>ReportList</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Settings</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    CONTET
</div>
<div id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
```